# Device Unable to Connect to Internet over WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, kali-linux

I tried both `ifconfig` and `iwconfig` in terminal, but still I can't spot any problem.

[image]

Comment: Can you ping outside the network? ifconfig will just tell you your current settings, that doesn't imply that you're communicating or not. Try ping 8.8.8.8, what do you get?

Comment: i only get this after hitting ping 8.8.8.8   PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.43.131 icmp_seq=21 Destination Host Unreachable

Comment: Then it implies that you're not routing outside your network. Try pinging your gateway, if you can hit your gateway, then your DNS needs to be checked. If you can't ping your gateway then your settings are incorrect for your network.

Comment: i tried pinging my gateway still the same error. my DNS is set on automatic mode.. i am able to access internet via usb tethring. but not in case wifi.

Comment: Now i am able to ping my gateway but still unable to access internet.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at this website:

http://cyberpratibha.com/blog/using-the-command-line-to-configure-network-interface-in-kali-linux/

Since you can't ping your gateway, you know the first point of problem(s). Try adding the gateway, and then pinging again. If you still can't ping, then look at how the wi-fi is routing, there might be an issue there, though if other devices can connect, then it still points to an issue on this device.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Tried as described in the link.. still no success.